# Bulk delete WooCommerce products that do not have featured image

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I own a site that have over 5000+ products imported and some of them do not have any images.

I would like to delete products that **do not** have any images and I was looking for some sort of bulk delete SQL command. Can it be done like that?

Brainstorming lead me to following sequence: create SQL command to assign no image products to certain category and then delete them manually from backend?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe the safest way is to trash all products that do not have images using SQL and manually empty trash from back-end?

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta where post_id in (SELECT id
FROM   `wp_posts` 
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE  `meta_key` ='_thumbnail_id') 
AND `post_type` = 'product' 
AND `post_status` = 'publish')
```

Comment: This gives me an error: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'wp_postmeta' for update in FROM clause